# Rewrite 2 select statements as one JOIN Statement

Tags: mysql, join

I've been strugling with a JOIN statement which I can't figure out.

I want to get the latest(newest) entry in two different tables and join the result in the output.

The 2 Select statements look like this and they work as expected but I can't seem to get the right result when I try to rewite them as a JOIN statement.

Please help, Thanks.

```
SELECT MaxNum 
FROM table1 
WHERE UserID = 4
ORDER BY Date DESC
LIMIT 1

SELECT MinNum 
FROM table2 
WHERE UserID = 4
ORDER BY Date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: you can use union as well

Comment: select Max( states.Id),max(City.id ) from States

inner join City on City.StateCode = states.code

where states.code = 'AL' , is it something you require ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that a join necessarily makes sense here.  However, you can slightly modify what you currently have to be one query:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT MaxNum FROM table1 WHERE UserID = 4 ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1) AS MaxNum,
    (SELECT MinNum FROM table2 WHERE UserID = 4 ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1) AS MinNum
```

Answer (score 0):

Since each of these queries only returns one row, one dirty trick you can use is to `cross join` the results:

```
SELECT MaxNum, MinNum
FROM   (SELECT   MaxNum 
        FROM     table1 
        WHERE    UserID = 4
        ORDER BY Date DESC
        LIMIT    1) t 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT   MinNum 
            FROM     table2 
            WHERE    UserID = 4
            ORDER BY Date DESC
            LIMIT    1) s
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display result as one row then use your queries as subqueries in `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  (SELECT MaxNum FROM table1 WHERE UserID = 4 ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT 1) AS q1,
  (SELECT MinNum FROM table2 WHERE UserID = 4 ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT 1) AS q2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select TOP 1 table1.MaxNum, table2.MinNum 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.UserID = table2.UserID 
WHERE table1.UserID = 4 
ORDER BY table1.Date DESC
```

Comment: table2 date has to sorted in descending order too